# Tkinter destroy button create by a loop

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, destroy

I want to create a reminder to remind me of the time I have chosen in the combobox by pressing the confirmed button. I put the time in a label and also create a delete button that can delete the label and button itself in the same row by a loop. It works if there's only one label, but if I increased the number of it it can only destroy the last label and button.

below is my code:

```
class final:
    def __init__(self,app):
        self.savelist=[]

        self.time= StringVar()
        self.timecombo = ttk.Combobox(app,textvariable=self.time)
        self.timecombo.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.timecombo.config(value =('1:00','2:00','3:00','4:00','5:00','6:00','7:00','8:00','9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00'))

        self.button1=Button(app,text='confirmed',command=self.save)
        self.button1.grid(row=3,column=2)


    ***def save(self):
        savetext = self.time.get()
        self.savelist.append(savetext)
        self.deletebutton_list = []
        self.savelabel_list = []
        for i in range(len(self.savelist)):
            savelabel = Label(app, text=self.savelist[i])
            savelabel.grid(row=4 + i, column=0)
            self.savelabel_list.append((savelabel))
            deletebutton = Button(app, text='delete' , command=functools.partial(self.deletelabel,idx=i))
            deletebutton.grid(row=4 + i, column=1)
            self.deletebutton_list.append(deletebutton)
    def deletelabel(self, idx):
        self.savelabel_list[idx].destroy()
        self.deletebutton_list[idx].destroy()
        self.savelist.remove(self.savelist[idx])
        self.savelabel_list.remove(self.savelabel_list[idx])
        self.deletebutton_list.remove(self.deletebutton_list[idx])***

app = Tk()
a = final(app)
app.title('things to do')
app.geometry("500x300+200+200")

app.mainloop()
```

I believed that there must be something wrong in the loop or the function deletelabel but I still can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.savelabel_list.remove(self.savelabel_list[idx])
```

Do not change the list.  If you delete label/button #1, then label #2 becomes #1, and so when you press the button to delete label #2, it deletes label #3 because everything has moved up.  Also, note that every time you call "save()" it creates a new set of widgets that overlay the old widgets, which will eventually slow down the computer.  Create and grid the new time label only.  Keep track of the row with a self.next_row variable (or whatever) and increment it by one each time.

Comment: thanks for your answer,but even if I delete the column you've recommended,I still can't achieve my goal,and I don't know how to crate and grid the new time label only,since I'm new in python. Could you write the code for me? thx.

Comment: and I think I've already solve the problem you've mentioned by using functools.partial,because I can see the right order of label/button in the list after I click it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that points out how usable classes are.  Create a new class, with label and a close button, for each reminder.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class NewButton:
    def __init__(self, master, label_text, this_row):
        ## put everything in a new frame so destroying
        ## one frame will destroy everything in it
        self.fr=Frame(master)
        self.fr.grid(row=this_row, column=1)

        Label(self.fr, text=label_text).grid(row=0, column=1)
        Button(self.fr, text="Close This",
               command=self.fr.destroy).grid(row=0, column=2)

class Final:
    def __init__(self,app):
        self.app=app
        self.this_row=4

        self.time_var= StringVar()
        self.timecombo = ttk.Combobox(app,textvariable=self.time_var)
        self.timecombo.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.button1=Button(app,text='confirmed',command=self.save)
        self.button1.grid(row=3,column=2)


    def save(self):
        save_text = self.time_var.get()
        self.this_row += 1
        next_button=NewButton(self.app, save_text, self.this_row)
        self.time_var.set("")

app = Tk()
a = Final(app)
app.title('things to do')
app.geometry("500x300+200+200")

app.mainloop()
```